# How to combine three files into one

Tags: awk

I've got a problem. I've got  three sequences of characters. Each one has  300 characters and they're in  different files. I want to divided them in 60s and combine into one.
characters are diffrent letters and *-+

This is scheme of my problem:

1.txt

```
aaaaaaa
```

2.txt

```
vvvvvvv
```

3.txt

```
ccccccc
```

I Would like to divided them in threes and combine this three files into one 4.txt.

Desired output:

```
aaa
vvv
ccc

aaa
vvv
ccc

a
v
C
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Also, as you indicate `awk` it means you know this tool can make it. so, what have you tried so far? You may be close to the solution.

Comment: -1 the question. If you have problem  and ask someone else, you should try your best to explain your problem clearly.  No one will know what do you want exactly by reading your question. E.g. file 1 has `7 a`, file2 has `7 v` file3 has `6 c` why one `a/v` was removed? which one should be removed? are your inputs always same letter? could they be multi-lines? what's rule to split to multi-parts? If you ask somebody to help you, please be serious.

Comment: Kent: Sorry for that: I think that my post is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it (using GNU awk for ARGC, ARGIND and FS=""):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=""; charsInGrp=3 }
{
    numRows=0
    for (grpNr=1;grpNr<=NF;grpNr+=charsInGrp) {
        ++numRows
        for (delta=0; delta<charsInGrp; delta++) {
            charGrp[ARGIND,numRows] = charGrp[ARGIND,numRows] $(grpNr+delta)
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1;rowNr<=numRows;rowNr++) {
        for (fileNr=1;fileNr<ARGC;fileNr++) {
            print charGrp[fileNr,rowNr]
        }
        print ""
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
aaa
vvv
ccc

aaa
vvv
ccc

a
v
c
```

Just change `charsInGrp=3` to whatever value you like, e.g. 60.